# Configuring emacs gdb behavior

Tags: gdb

I've been using gdb in emacs for a bit now and I mostly love it, but there are some minor quirks about its behavior that I find bothersome and I wanted to know how to go about tweaking them. I also want to say I know almost nothing about modifying emacs in general.

I've been using `gdb-many-windows` when I debug. The thing I want to change is the behavior around breakpoints. After a breakpoint is hit, the source window moves to the line I placed the breakpoint on. This is good, I like that. But after that, if I move to a different part of the source file myself and then run any gdb command, the source window will automatically move back to the line containing the breakpoint. So if I want to, say, set a breakpoint at a different line of the source file, the moment I do so the source window snaps back to the first breakpoint. This has me constantly moving up and down the source file.

Is there any way I can change this? I've tried googling and I can't seem to find anything about this.

Comment: I suggest `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: I didn't realize this was a bug. Is this not the expected behavior?

Comment: Other than habit, who would expect this behavior and why?  Your description clearly states that *you* consider it as a bug (or at least a misfeature).  `report-emacs-bug` should also be used for feature requests, BTW.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it was weird but I tried it on two completely different emacs on two completely different systems  so I figured it might just be the expected behavior. Maybe it has something to do with the program I'm debugging? 

Anyways, thanks for the help.